# Which R command displays the whole dataframe data and structure in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Anyone knows which R command gives this dataframe structure printed when I use it?

```
re<-structure(list(month_year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                                              7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, NA), .Label = c("2020-Mar", 
                                                                                                   "2020-Apr", "2020-May", "2020-Jun", "2020-Jul", "2020-Aug", "2020-Sep", 
                                                                                                   "2020-Oct", "2020-Nov", "2020-Dec", "2021-Jan", "2021-Feb", "2021-Mar", 
                                                                                                   "2021-Apr"), class = "factor"), First = c(862, 19117, 121572, 
                                                                                                                                             588123, 882046, 1401836, 1065476, 813419, 834485, 916300, 1264637, 
                                                                                                                                             1369098, 2025535, 474664, 267236), lab = c("862", "19,117", "121,572", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "588,123", "882,046", "1,401,836", "1,065,476", "813,419", "834,485", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "916,300", "1,264,637", "1,369,098", "2,025,535", "474,664", 
                                                                                                                                                                                        "267,236")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `dput`.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completion sake, I'll add an answer.

`dput` command would keep you data, structure and classes of data intact and will make it available in easy to copy format.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
dput(df)

structure(list(a = 1:5, b = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

It works for all the data structures. For example, for a vector -

```
dput(letters[1:5])
c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```